# How can i pass an optional parameter to a python class using argparse function in python

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python script `script.py` that has the below `init` function

```
def __init__(self):
    """init method for the class."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test")
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--user', dest='user',
                        default='', required=True,
                        action="store", help="the script running user")
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--url', dest='url',
                        default="", required=True,
                        action="store", help="url")
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--env', nargs='*',
                        dest='env',help="the env type")
    parsers = parser.parse_args()
    self.user = parsers.user.strip()
    self.url = parsers.url.strip()
    self.env = parsers.args.env.strip()
```

The `env` type stores 2 values either `test` or `prod`. The `env` parameter should be optional, if values is not provided it should take default values as `prod` or else it should store any of the values provided(test/prod). if no value for env is passed, the default value should be `prod`
I tried making the `env` param as optional using `nargs` but when my script executes it throws me the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 185, in <module>
    obj = script()
  File "script.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.env_type = parsers.args.env_type.strip()
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'args'
```

I am executing my script as

```
python script.py -u <user> -i <url> -e <env>
```

Ideally i want my script to execute even when `-e` option is not provided.
How should i change my script?

Comment: `parsers` seems to be a strange name for the parsed arguments and that might have confused you.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `strip()`.  The shell splits the commandline on white space, so there shouldn't be any extraneous blanks (unless you are quoting strings).

Comment: With `nargs='*'`, `parsers.env` will be a list of strings.  I strongly recommend printing the namespace during debugging, `print(parsers)` so you see exactly what argparse has done with your input.  Then you won't be guessing and using wrong expressions like `parsers.args.env_type.strip()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the env to be either "prod" or "test", you can use `choices` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices)), with a default value:

`parser.add_argument('-e', '--env', choices=['prod', 'test'], default='prod', help="the env type")`

This will raise an error if something else is passed to `--env`.

Note that flags with dashes like `-e` `--env` are assumed optional in argparse ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required))

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be without `args`?:

```
self.env = parsers.env.strip()
```

also you could handle the AttributeError:

```
try:
    self.env = parsers.env.strip()
except AttributeError:
    self.env = 'prod'
```

Comment: You are correct it's ```args = parser.parse_args() print(args.env.strip())``` which gives `<env>`

Comment: @Cloudomation no when i do self.env = parsers.env.strip() it throws me this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 185, in <module>
    obj = script()
  File "script.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.env = parsers.env.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Since you are using `nargs='*'`, the env argument is a list. The strip method is for strings

Comment: You should use the `choices` option as in pdpinos answer